# Is http://stackflow.info/ anyhow related to Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, security, copycat-sites

I've found this site in Google Search results: `http://stackflow.info/`

It is related anyhow with Stack Overflow official site?
If not, how can I report it to Stack Overflow administrators?

Comment: It redirects me to `fast-cash.club`, full of ads and spam. Not good...